# What happens to the limit of an inverse function if the function converges?

Tags: limits, functions

Is there a theorem of what happens to $\lim_{x\to n}f^{-1}(x)$ if $$\lim_{x\to n}f(x) \to m \qquad \mathbb{where} \quad m,n \in \mathbb N,\{0\}$$?

Assuming $\quad f^{-1}(x), \ f(x)$ are continuous functions.

Comment: It depends on the property of the mapping $f$

Comment: Is there a theorem for functions that have certain properties?

Comment: e.g. If $f(x)=x$, you know it also gonna be $m$, but in general, the values in domain does not need to have any relationship with the value in the range

Comment: Note that there are continuous (even bijective) functions whose inverse are discontinuous.

Comment: @lappen68 And I think it is actually not quite related to continuous yet. Notice that the both $x$ is approaching to $n$, but one $x$ is in the function domain, the other is in the function range. Even if $f$ is both continuous and open mapping, it does not help

Comment: I think you may handle it as a vector limit $(x; f(x))$ transforming to $(f^{-1}(x); x)$.